# how to read a sound file (mp3)

Tags: android, file, mp3

***how to  open and  read  a sound file ? 
My purpose is when click on Button read   music open and I listen this file***

I do not know how to open an mp3 file and read this file contenut

how, which the permission is there a tutorial and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you just want to play a local MP3 file. Correct?

You should read the official [API guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html). It will tell you everything you need to know!

Here are a few snippets from the guide:

How you might play from local storage:

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

What permissions do you need?

> 1. **Internet Permission** - If you are using MediaPlayer to stream network-based content, your application must request network access.
> 2. **Wake Lock Permission** - If your player application needs to keep the screen from dimming or the processor from sleeping, or uses the MediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying() or MediaPlayer.setWakeMode() methods, you must request this permission.